# Color picker while editing ''Box-shadow" CSS property

Tags: css, dreamweaver

The question is, how can I display the color picker while I'm giving form to the box-shadow property on dreamweaver? I find it complicated to memorize all color codes and quite impractical lol

```
{
box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 2px (Color picker doesn't display in this part)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This question seems to be about how to _use_ Dreamweaver, which is not a question about _programming_ and therefore off-topic for Stackoverflow. If so, this question would be better on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). I'm voting to close and migrate the question, unless you clarify this has something to do with _programming._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing `Ctrl` + `Space` brings up a code suggestion box, then click on "Color...", which brings up the Color Picker.

Also, right-clicking brings up the context menu, go to "Code Hint Tools" submenu and then click on "Color Picker".

Incidentally, you can also go to "Edit" on the top menu bar, go down to "Code Hint Tools" and then click on "Color Picker".